# Why hover is not working with this type of html?

Tags: css

Why hover is not working with this type of html?

```css
***.bar*****
{
      display: none;
}
**.trip:hover .bar**
{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="trip">≡</span>

<div class="bar">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `.trip:hover .bar` states that `.bar` is a child of `.trip`, and in this case it is not, it's a sibling. Solve it by changing it for `.trip:hover + .bar` or `.trip:hover ~ .bar`.

```css
.bar
{
      display: none;
}
.trip:hover + .bar
{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="trip">≡</span>

<div class="bar">Example</div>
```

Here you have a complete list of CSS selectors, so that you can learn how to use them properly: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp